# How to merge two nodes together and retain all links to the nodes in NEO4j / Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to merge 2 nodes together in NEO4j.

Each node has it's own independent set of links to nodeA and nodeB.

I want to merge all the attributes between nodeA and nodeB together as they have some different properties. Whilst also retaining all the links to both nodes in the newly merged node.

How would I go about even doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at **APOC Procedures**. The procedure `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` does exactly what you are looking for.

```sql
MATCH (f:Person {name:'Foo'}), (b:Person {surname:'Bar'})
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([f,b])
YIELD node RETURN node
```

Docs and examples: https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/